# how is the rails way include all user custom helper files in view component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-components

```rb
class ApplicationViewComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end

class FooComponent < ApplicationViewComponent 
end
```

How can I include not only ApplicationHelper but also user created all helper files in view component?

Answer (score 3):

### You don't include all the helpers.

Use the `helpers` proxy instead to access your Rails helpers.

```ruby
class UserComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def profile_icon
    helpers.icon :user
  end
end
```

And use `delegate` if you want to simplify the calls:

```
class UserComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  delegate :icon, to: :helpers

  def profile_icon
    icon :user
  end
end
```

Only include the helper modules when actually needed.

Comment: While you can at least in theory you could figure out all the constants in the `app/helpers` directory and then include each one that would be duplicating the functionality of ActionView and not a very good practice as it would confuse documention generation tools and other developers.